# SQL onde está o erro?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Já revisei várias vezes essa query mas não acho o erro.

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dbg0' (`filename`,`src`,`hash`,`time`) VALUES ('20170714214510th-freifejrfg.png' at line 1"
```

O código PHP é esse:

```
private function insert_db($filename, $src, $hash) {
    try {
        $insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO :tabela (`filename`,`src`,`hash`,`time`) VALUES (:filename, :src, :hash, :time)");
        $insert->bindValue(':tabela', $this->table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindValue(':filename', $filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindValue(':src', $src, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindValue(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindValue(':time', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->execute();
        $this->lestId = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        if ($this->lestId > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->error = "Falha ao registrar imagem " . $insert->errorInfo();
            return FALSE;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e;
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Fiz também uma função para retorna a query pronta para testa-lá:

```
public function sql($filename, $src, $hash) {
    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table (`filename`,`src`,`hash`,`time`) VALUES ('$filename', '$src', '$hash','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
}
```

A mesma retornou: "INSERT INTO dbg0 (`filename`,`src`,`hash`,`time`) VALUES ('20170714214510th-freifejrfg.png', '/var/www/html/mysite/img/postagens/', 'ad7473acb6a4d5135dbb0a01a649ef48','2017-07-14 21:45:10')" Testei direto na base é inseriu sem problemas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acredito que o problema é ter um parametro para o nome da tabela, creio que não funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182910/php-pdo-bind-table-name

Comment: Percebeu que na mensagem de erro, no nome da tabela, há uma aspa simples sobrando? Talvez seja este o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
    $insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table (`filename`,`src`,`hash`,`time`) VALUES (:filename, :src, :hash, :time)");
    $insert->bindValue(':filename', $filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    ...
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas por que ?

Comment: php, pdo, não é minha área, mas nunca vi passar o nome da tabela como parâmetro do comando...

Comment: Provavelmente porque quando você faz o `bind`, o PDO adiciona aspas simples ao valor e, no SQL, nome da tabela não recebe aspas. No máximo crases.